# Как поймать ошибку с Telegrama?

Tags: php, laravel

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

try {
    $telegram = new \Telegram\Bot\Api(env('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'));
    $telegram->setAsyncRequest(true)
        ->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => env('TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID'),
            'text' => "..." . PHP_EOL,
            'parse_mode' => 'html'
        ]);
} catch (RequestException $e){

    Mail::send(...
    return false;
}
```

Получаю вот:

> Client error: `POST https://api.telegram.org/botххх/sendMessage` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{"ok":false,"

Проблема в том что при ошибке я не попадаю в блок catch

Comment: Получаете где, по почте? Можно ещё в лог писать `Log::error('Telegram API Request Error: ' . $e->getMessage());`

Comment: @DiMithras Проблема в том что при ошибке я не попадаю в блок catch

Comment: Ну, логика подсказывает мне, что для `setAsyncRequest(true)` это правильное и ожидаемое поведение

Comment: @andreymal и как пофиксать?